# which is Better in typeorm Save Or Update

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I was working on a project and I wanted to update the data but I don't know which is the faster way to update data SAVE() method or Update()

```
this.repo.save({
id:id,
data})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use **update()** for update entity partially.

- Unlike **save()** method executes a primitive operation without cascades, relations and other operations included.
- Executes fast and efficient UPDATE query.

Answer (score 10):

Actually they are for different purposes

**save()**
it saves the entity you provided if your entry doesn't have an identifier (id) or the id doesn't exist in the DB, it tries to create a new one. Otherwise, it updates the entity itself.

**update()**
it executes a simple `UPDATE table SET....` query. It means you can use it for updating an entity 'partially'. It's handy for 'patching' things.

TL;TR

- use `save()` for creating a new record or updating the whole entity at once
- use `update()` for updating an entity partially.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help and i really appreciate your support ........!!!! but I need to know which method is more faster in querying like taking less time and more optimize way

Comment: if you want to update a record; `update()` would be faster. Because you don't need to fetch the actual record itself, you can directly call the update with the id and fields you want to update.

Comment: then what is the difference and use case of upsert?

Comment: and save will update or create new one , on which condition save willl update? can i pass custom criteria for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah definitely, update is more quick. But here is the actual difference.

while using save in typeorm, we are getting entity instance first and then saving data. By doing so we can use hooks like AfterInsert, BeforeInsert.

Pros: We can use hooks
Cons: It will take 2 db calls for update as first we get entity to be updated

Update: directly update entity, but doing so we cant use hooks there

So there is a tradeoff .

One may refer typeorm API references for more details